# Calculating response time for hbase client RPC call

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, rpc

I'm using Hbase 1.x and compliant java hbase client to query. I have hbase grafana with me. But unable to figure out total response time for the request.

Was looking at **Scan Next latencies, RPC queued time and RPC process time**.

Can I conclude response time from only these metrics? If yes How?

Do I need to consider any other metrics which should I look for?

screenshots attached for both.

RPC call queued time

[image: rpc call queued time max]

Scan next latencies

[image: Scan Next latencies]

RPC call process time

[image: RPC call process time]

How do calculate the total response time from these and do I need to consider other factors too?